# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object while posting relational data

Tags: json, angular, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

Ok there are a lot of questions and answers with this, if you know an exact duplicate of this please point me there but I am too dumb to understand how to make it work.

I want to add a worker to a job and everything is good until reaches ModelState. Here are the steps I am doing.

1. Filling the form
2. I submit the form and console breakpoint.

   ```
   Name = "test", Description = "test", 
              worker = {Id: 21, FirstName: "Will", LastName: "Smith", Job: null}
   ```
3. Angular service in console

   ```
   jobs = {Name: "test", Description: "test", worker: {…}}

   Not sure why the dots in the brackets.
   ```
4. Reaches API method and fails modelstate.

   ```
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }
   ```

In browser console I get:

```
Message:"The request is invalid."

ModelState:job.worker.Id:["Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {…N object. Path 'worker.Id', line 1, position 16."]
```

Full error message from ModelState is:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[TestRotaru.Models.Worker]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'worker.Id', line 1, position
>   51.

Alright so far this is like a duplicate question but I tried few things and I don't understand some things in answers.
I tried to decorate my models with attributes such as:

```
  These on top of the class
//[Serializable]
//[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
//[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]

  On properties
//[JsonProperty]
```

Now the thing I have no clue and I don't understand:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
                <Dictionary<string, Item>>(*Where this string comes from*);
```

This is just an example, I am concerned about that string in brackets not about if is a Dictionary or something else.

Here is my method:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Job))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostJob(Job job)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        job.DueDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.Job.Add(job);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = job.Id }, job);
    }
```

In all the answers about this everyone has that random json string in the round brackets... From where I am supposed to have that?

Here are my models:

Job Model:

```
//[Serializable]
//[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
//[Serializable()]
//[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Job
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty]
    //[System.Runtime.Serialization.IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Worker> Worker { get; set; }
}
```

Worker Model:

```
//[Serializable]
//[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
//[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Worker
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty]
    //[System.Runtime.Serialization.IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Job { get; set; }
}
```

Angular component and service:

```
add(Name: string, Description: string, worker): void {
    this.jobsServices.addJob({Name, Description, worker } as Jobs)
        .subscribe(jobs => {
            this.jobs.push(jobs);
        });
}

addJob(jobs: Jobs): Observable<Jobs> {
    return this.http.post<Jobs>(this.apiURL, jobs, httpOptions);
}

div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="labelInputs">Select Worker</label><br>
        <select [(ngModel)]="worker" class="form-control">
          <option [value]="0">Select Worker</option>
          <option *ngFor="let worker of workers" [ngValue]="worker">{{worker.FirstName}} {{worker.LastName}}</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

```
<button class="brn btn-lg btn-block btn-change" (click)="add(name.value, desc.value, worker)">Add Job</button>
```

Alright is a long question but I wanted to prove myself I did my research and I just didn't thrown the error message and ask for solutions but this is really getting on my nerves.

Since I am posting relational data and my console shows `ModelState{job.worker.Id: [,…]}` how do I deserialize this? Plus my ModelState shows the worker as null when reaches the API, I can guess because is not converted from json, but worth to know.

Thank you for help.

Comment: The object you submitted has a property "worker". This property is a object of class Worker but it's NOT an array. Your API expect an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that on your SPA you are sending `worker` as a single object and your API expects a list (array) of workers. Now I don't know what you want.. but you can either fix it by changing your API model to expect a single worker or change your SPA to send a list of workers. That no one can answer you.. depends on your app's requirements. But, my best guess is that a Job might have several workers. So:

**Api Models (mostly the same.. just removed the attributes and changed Worker to Workers):**

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }

    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Worker> Workers { get; set; }
}


public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // This is an "array". your spa needs to send in this format.
    public virtual ICollection<Job> Job { get; set; }
}
```

**Spa Code:**

```
export class Job {
    id: int;
    name: string;
    // other fields here..

    // Workers property that maps API model
    workers: Array<Worker>;

    constructor(id: int, name: string [other fields..]) {
        this.id = id;
        // and so on..
    }

    public addWorker(worker) {
        this.workers.push(worker);
    }
}

export class Worker {
    id: int;
    firstName: string;
    // other fields here.. No need for array of jobs here!
}
```

With this model, you can do this before calling the API (on add function):

```
add(Name: string, Description: string, worker: Worker): void {

    // creates a job using constructor
    const job = new Job(name, description);

    // add Job via function(can even be more complex and add validation and so on..)
    job.addWorker(worker);

    this.jobsServices.addJob(job)
        .subscribe(jobs => {
            this.jobs.push(jobs);
        });
}
```

This will call the api with a json like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "some name",
    [ other fields..]
    "workers": [
        { "id:" 1, "name": "some worker name" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you man for your awesome input! I am sorry it took me so long to respond I left yesterday and today I was kinda busy with some other things. I am learning Angular and its pretty weird to me somehow. In console everything looks good but the worker doesn't reach my api with the Job. I get the error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` I did this `workers: Array<Worker> = [];` in the spa model but I think isn't right even if I don't get any error. I will try to find why doesn't reach the controller, but I will mark your answer because is gods work here. Thank you

Comment: Alright figured what was the problem. Thank you very much this wasn't just an answer to a problem. I just did learned a lot about Angular, I was unaware I should use keyword `Array` I was thinking `[]` its considered array. And I didn't knew I need to use a constructor there or I can use methods like that in the same class. I tried to shove everything in the component method header to the api to deal with it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to initialize the array :). Glad it was helpful. Also, you don't need to use constructors and all that.. that's just what Typescript gives you. Suggest you take a look at the typescript docs cos it is really helpful. Your life writing angular apps will be much more easier after that. Good luck!